# How add Taildwind to CRA (jsx) with SASS

Tags: sass, create-react-app, tailwind-css

I hope this help to you to fix this case:
I have a app created with next configuration:

```
npx create-react-app my-project
cd my-project
```

Next I config Sass

```
npm install sass
# or
yarn add sass
```

Next I updated my files `.css` by `.scss` (src/index.css by src/index.scss)

Next step, in public folder in my html add the next code

```
<style lang="sass">
    @import url("src/index.scss");
</style>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem was that there was TMI to do it, this post is just to simplify the steps 

Answer (score 2):

To install tailwind:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Add the paths to all of your template files in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */ 
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Next add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers to your `./src/index.scss` file.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Finally

You can use all Tailwind classes in any path where you have your project components inside the "./src" path

I hope it helps you!